# Zope page template metadata not being read in Products

Tags: plone, zope

My application runs on Zope 2.12.19 and Python 2.6.5.

There is a page template file `pagetemplate.pt` with access restrictions defined in the `pagetemplate.pt.metadata` file. These access restrictions apply and work correctly for all web pages except for the ones in Zope Products.

The contents of the `.metadata` file are below:

```
[default]
title=

[security]
View=0:Authenticated,Manager,Owner,User
Access contents information=0:Authenticated,Manager,Owner,User
```

For example, there is a Zope Product that lists all the users in the system and this uses the above page template. The user can access this page anonymously without logging in which implies that the metadata file is not being read.

But to access any other page outside Products, the application forces the user to log in.
Is there a problem with Products reading `.metadata` files?

FYI - I do not use ZODB... instead everything (source code) is on the file system.

The content of `configure.zcml` is below.

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    i18n_domain="AMSPermissions">

    <!-- the users manage page -->
    <browser:page
    for="OFS.interfaces.IFolder"
    name="manage-users"
    template="standard_template.pt"
    class=".users.UsersView"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />

    <!-- permissions checker -->
    <browser:page
    for="OFS.interfaces.IFolder"
    name="perm_check"
    class=".permissions.PermissionsCheckerView"
    permission="zope2.View"
    allowed_interface=".interfaces.IPermissionsCheckerView"
    />
</configure>.
```

Also, below is the sample code from the Product.

```
<html metal:use-macro="context/standard_template/macros/page">
  <metal:block fill-slot="heading">Users Overview</metal:block>
  <metal:block fill-slot="body" tal:define="users view/get_users">
     ---------Some code--------
  </metal:block>
</html>
```

Comment: Are these page templates defined in a skin or are they used with browser views (e.g. defined in `configure.zcml`)?

Comment: They are used with browser views. For example, list-users.pt defined in configure.zcml accesses the page template file.

Answer (score 3):

`.metadata` files *only* apply to skin objects. For browser views, you need to specify permissions in the ZCML configuration of the views:

```
<browser:page
    for="*"
    name="somepagename"
    template="pagetemplate.pt"
    permission="zope.View"
    />
```

You specify permissions; the context defines what roles have what permissions.

Comment: @Ravi: The answer is generic on purpose; I am answering *why* your .metadata files are being ignored, and giving you a pointer to how permissions are handled for browser views instead. It is not meant as a ready-to-go answer for your specific situation.

Comment: @Ravi: The exact configuration needed for your application is going to take a lot more explaining; please do try and figure that out for yourself and come back here to SO if you have specific questions to help you understand the issues.

Comment: That makes sense. But can you tell me why the security restrictions apply (I mean `.metadata` file is read) when ZODB is used instead of it being file system based. The `configure.zcml` also does not include the template attribute in it and it prompts the user to login whenever any product is directly accessed from the browser.

Comment: @Ravi: You are talking about two very different systems here; the ZODB machinery is CMF-skin based (so part of the Content Management Framework package), which pre-dates the ZCA (Zope Component Framework); the latter defines views and pages and adapters.

Comment: @Ravi: you can define skin elements in the file system too, and *then* metadata files are used. But if you use ZCA views (and you should, really), then different rules apply. The CMF is not consulted at all.

Comment: I actually made a typo in the `.metadata` file to find out if it is actually being read or not. Now, when I launch the product page in the browser, in the Zope log it does show the typo error in the `.metadata` file. So, this suggests that it is being read and overridden. And as far as the `permission` attribute in `configure.zcml` is concerned, `zope2.View` is permitting Anonymous users to log in and I do not understand why is that happening.

Comment: @Ravi: It was an *example permission*; and if you do not give the View permission to anonymous users (for the *context of the view*) then anonymous won't see this. Do you or do you not have these files in a CMF skin? `.metadata` files are *only* read for skin objects.

Comment: The permission was already set in the file and works fine when I use ZODB. It is not something that I have newly done. Also, I do not understand when you say skin based.. is this not Plone framework that you are talking about ? I do not use Plone. All I have done is to use the dumper to dump the entire code onto the file system and the template file is a part of this. Products located in external directories access this template. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24464/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-ravi)

Comment: @Ravi: Hope the chat could help you further, would you mind to accept Martijn's answer, please?

Comment: @IdaEbkes: We never connected up in chat, unfortunately.